# Positive linear functional on an involutive Banach algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

Why is every positive linear functional on an involutive Banach algebra with a bounded approximate continuous?

Answer (score 0):

This is a result of Varopoulos. You'll find it in

> R. S. Doran and V. A. Belfi, *[Characterizations of C${}^*$-algebras: The Gelfand–Naimark theorems](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=6jNbsnJVjMoC&lpg=PA70&ots=IhX4e2TEb_&dq=%22without%20an%20approximate%20identity%22&hl=pl&pg=PA69#v=onepage&q=%22without%20an%20approximate%20identity%22&f=false)*. Monographs Textbooks Pure Appl. Math. 101.

on p. 69.